# in_avail() is not returning correct number of bytes available after a sgetn(..,..) call

Tags: c++, streambuf

I have a input file(35413 bytes) and I am opening it using **std::ifstream** object and getting pointer to its buffer in a **std::streambuf** pointer. I am trying get remaining bytes in the stream using **in_avail()** function after every read. Below is the sample code for the same.

```
 class A{
 private:
    std::ifstream _stream;
    std::streambuf * buff;
 public:
    A(std::string fileName);
    int RemainingBytes();
    uint8_t getUInt8();
    void Read(uint8_t * buf, uint64_t len);
};




A::A(std::string path){
    _stream.open(path, std::ios::binary);
    if(_stream.is_open()){
        buff = _stream.rdbuf();
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Error: Unable to open file" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
int A::RemainingBytes(){
    return this->buff->in_avail() ;
}
uint8_t A::getUInt8(){
    uint8_t n;
    this->Read(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*> (&n),1);
    return n;
}
void A::Read(uint8_t * buf, uint64_t len){
    this->buff->sgetn(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf), static_cast<std::size_t>(len));
}




int main(){
    A reader("file.abc");
    std::cout << reader.RemainingBytes() << std::endl;
    reader.getUInt8();
    std::cout << reader.RemainingBytes() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Output:

    35413
    510
```

So when checking remaining bytes just after opening it is showing correct number of bytes but after reading 1 byte it should show (previous result - 1). I am not able to figure out why this is happening. I can not call **egptr()** and **gptr()** functions on this buffer as they are protected. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just check the documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/in_avail

Note the distinction between an empty buffer and a non-empty buffer. In one case, it reports the number of characters already loaded into the buffer, in the other it calls `showmanyc`, which "Estimates the number of characters available for input in the associated character sequence".

What are you trying to achieve? Guessing, I see two alternatives paths:

1. Just read the file one byte at a time. This means you can't determine the number of bytes available and subsequently that you can't base your behaviour on that information.
2. Memory-map the file. This is initially more setup code but then it gives you something resembling an array of `uint8_t` values, which seems to be close to what you want.

Comment: I have checked the documentation and I have one doubt that why showmanyc() is getting called as buffer is loaded when file is opened and I am reading only 1 byte then how the buffer is getting empty?.

Comment: No, the buffer is *not* loaded when opening the file, it is only loaded on demand.

Comment: For the first time when _in_avail()_ is called is it returning the value of `egptr()-gptr()` or _showmanyc()_? if it's the first case then how is the value of _gptr_ is changing this much after reading the first byte so that it has to call _showmanyc()_? If it is the second case then how the return value of _showmanyc()_ is varying this much.

Comment: Before reading anything, the buffer is empty so it calls `showmanyc()`. In order to read a single character, it fills the buffer with data, but it doesn't load the whole file. In your case, it seems to load 511 characters, so after returning one 510 remain buffered.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for clarifying.